# ObHighchartsBundle: custom and set correctly xAxis with datetime and interval from DQL queries

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, highcharts, doctrine-orm

I am using marcaube/[ObHighchartsBundle](https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle) in my Symfony project

In my controller, I have this code with my queries for the highchart/graphic:

```
$series = array(
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Conso ECS',
                    'type'  => 'spline',
                    'color' => '#003171',
                    'yAxis' => 1,
                    'data'  => $dataConsoECS, //first query from my repo
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Consommation Chaleur',
                    'type'  => 'spline',
                    'color' => '#049372',
                    'yAxis' => 1,
                    'data'  => $dataConsoChaleur, //second query from my repo
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Température extérieure',
                    'type'  => 'spline',
                    'color' => '#FAA945',
                    'data'  => $dataTemperatures, //third query from my repo
                ),
            );
            $yData = array(
                array(
                    'labels' => array(
                        'style'     => array('color' => '#FAA945'),
                    ),
                    'title' => array(
                        'text'  => 'Temperature',
                        'style' => array('color' => '#FAA945')
                    ),
                    'opposite' => true,
                ),
                array(
                    'labels' => array(
                        'style'     => array('color' => '#6C7A89')
                    ),
                    'gridLineWidth' => 0,
                    'title' => array(
                        'text'  => 'Consommation',
                        'style' => array('color' => '#6C7A89')
                    ),
                ),
            );

            $ob = new Highchart();
            $ob->chart->renderTo('newFlo'); // The #id of the div where to render the chart
            $ob->chart->type('linechart');
            $ob->title->text('Graphique à 3 échelles');
            $ob->xAxis->title(array('text'  => "Dates"));
            $ob->xAxis->categories($arrayResultHours); //my last query which return an array of datetimes 
            $ob->xAxis->type('datetime');
            $ob->yAxis($yData);
            $ob->series($series);

            return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:graphique.html.twig', array(
            'chartChoice' => $chartRender, 'chart' => $ob));
    }
```

This is the result I have:
[image]

Like you can see, all of my datetimes from the query are in my xAxis label and set automatically the interval. I just need to set my own interval hours per hours and make my datetime appears when I pass over my indexes of my series, like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-pointstart-datetime/) or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9xpekowg/3/) too.

As you can see, I have well my 3 series from a DQL. The las one concerning the datetimes is the time (the hour) where the conso are identified.

But, in fact, I'm trying to have this results on my xAxis:

```
y|
 |
 |
 |_____________________________________________
   00h00  01h00  02h00  03h00  to ......  23h00
```

I don't want to have my datetimes where the conso are identified, but a day interval like I try to represent you just above.

So the xAxis label must have a day interval from 00h00 to 23h00 but my series must have to show my datetimes from my database. This is where I am lost, because I need to set an interval hours to hours, but my series have to point on a datetime from my query.

I have found [this](https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle/issues/61), but I did not find my solution yet. I need to parameter my xAxis like this?

```
$ob->xAxis->type('datetime');
$ob->xAxis->tickInterval((24 * 3600 * 1000));
```

Someone know how can I set correctly the xAxis with ObHighchartsBundle?

Comment: Remove categories from your chart: `$ob->xAxis->categories($arrayResultHours);`. Now, set `datetime` type and `tickItnerval`. The last and most important thing is that point should be an array of x and y. In js like this: `[x, y]`.

Comment: @PawełFus, I understand that set a query on `$categories ` is not the solution, but how can I have an interval hour per hour on xAxis and my series pointed on the datetime of my database? That is to say, I need to create an xAxis with all hour of a day, with one hour of interval, but in my database I should have temperature pointed on a datetime like `2015-05-05 00:03:08` for example.
Mostly, this one is for one day, but I have to make user allow to see a graphic for **each day of a week**, **each week of a month** and **each month of a year**. Thank you by the way for answer to my question.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Then try my solution. `tickInterval` will take care of xAxis to display labels. And dates like `2015-05-05 00:03:08` will be handled automatically, when you will create points as arrays/object. Just make sure each point contains info about `x` as **timestamp** in **milliseconds** and `y` as value.

Comment: @PawełFus your solution is the good one, make an answer in order to close this post. Indeed I have to create points as arrays/object. And each point must contains info about x as timestamp in milliseconds and y as value.

Answer (score 0):

Remove categories from your chart:

```
$ob->xAxis->categories($arrayResultHours);.
```

Now, set `datetime` type and `tickInterval`. 
The last and most important thing is that point should be an array of x and y. In js like this: `[x, y]`, where `x` is timestamp in milliseconds and `y` is value (number).